# Will Amazon ELB clone my Apache conf file from saved instance when starting up a new one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, load-balancing

Hi guys & thank you in advance, for this noobie question!

I've just set up load balancing (classic) for my app in AWS &, TBH, i'm not entirely sure it's going to work that well!

I need all HTTP traffic to be re-directed to HTTPS, so had to change the "primary" instance's Apache Conf file to set up a redirect.

All's great & it works file, but i'm worried this change won't be reflected in any new instances, fired up by load-balancing to meet demand.

I've saved the "primary" as the template configuration, but still not convinced this will work: the last thing I want is re-do this change, every time a new instance starts-up.

Am I right to be worried, or will the saved configuration actually keep the changes (I.E. it's like a ghosted disk image rather then an sort of unattended install, so to speak).

As you can tell, i'm very new to cloud-services, so any help will gratefully received!

Many thanks
Mal

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved an AMI of your primary instance that is configured correctly (and will auto start Apache), then any new instances that are loaded from this image will have exactly the same configuration.

You will be able to check this in your `Launch Configuration` for your `Auto-Scaling Group` (found on the EC2 sidebar) that you will have created in order to meet demand by specifying which AMI to use when scaling up.

You can also set a minimum amount of instances in the Auto-Scaling Group so that 2 instances are always in existence, and you can test if the second instance redirects correctly by removing the primary instance from the ELB temporarily.

Comment: Many thanks, Deif for your swift & detailed response. You've put my mind at ease! Have a great weekend